# OrientDB SQL "slow" when using different types of index

Tags: sql, indexing, database-performance, orientdb

I have a Document database with just one class. This class contains the following properties:

```
Position: long
Label: string
Source: string
```

I also created the following indexes:

```
INDEX_TYPE.NOTUNIQUE on Position (to use range queries),
INDEX_TYPE.NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX on Source,
INDEX_TYPE.NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX on Label
```

Now when i run a select query that filters by Source and/or Label the query is very fast (returning in 0 seconds) and also when i use a range query filtering by Position only (with BETWEEN) the query is also very fast.
The problem appears when i use a filter by Source (or Label) and also by Position. In this case the query takes 23/24 seconds.
The database has 1 million records.
Example of fast queries:

```
select from classname where Source = 'A';
select from classname where Source = 'A' AND Label = 'B';
```

Example of slow queries:

```
select from classname where Source = 'A' AND Position Between 100 and 120;
```

I can probably create a composite index on both Source and Position / Label and Position / all 3 fields, but i just want to know if this might be a 'bug' or is the expected behaviour.

Update:
After some more testing, it seems the 'problem' is not exactly the different types of index, but using different types of data in the Where clause. when that happens, OrientDb doesn't use the indexes, it seems.
Also, using a composite index does indeed speed up the queries. But this does not seem to be a solution, since i would have to create indexes for all the combinations of queries that i could use.

Update 2:
After some more testing i'm seeing the problem is related with the use of the indexes. I changed the indexes to:

```
INDEX_TYPE.UNIQUE on Position (to use range queries),
INDEX_TYPE.NOTUNIQUE on Source,
INDEX_TYPE.UNIQUE on (Position,Source)
```

and the queries on Position only work fine. Queries on (Position and Source) work fine but queries on (Source and Position), ie changing the order of filter on  Where clause, work very slow.
The "explain" on this composite query returns:

```
{limit:-1,compositeIndexUsed:1,fullySortedByIndex:false,evaluated:1000001,documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass:1000001,sourceId:9d3c4a78-78bc-4ef5-bae5-31011dd4867d,START:0,involvedIndexes:[1],indexIsUsedInOrderBy:false,END:77,current:#9:986891,fetchingFromTargetElapsed:22332,documentReads:1000001,recordReads:1000001,elapsed:23090.744,resultType:collection,resultSize:77}
```

If i change the composite index (3) to:

```
INDEX_TYPE.UNIQUE on (Source, Position)
```

then all the queries work fine.

The "explain" on this composite query returns:

```
{limit:-1,compositeIndexUsed:1,fullySortedByIndex:false,evaluated:77,documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass:77,sourceId:9d3c4a78-78bc-4ef5-bae5-31011dd4867d,START:0,involvedIndexes:[1],indexIsUsedInOrderBy:false,END:77,current:#9:76,fetchingFromTargetElapsed:4,documentReads:77,recordReads:77,elapsed:4.298701,resultType:collection,resultSize:77}
```

So it seems the way we create the indexes and the position of the properties in the Where clause are correlated.

Comment: can you post explain of
select from classname where Source = 'A' AND Position Between 100 and 120;
I think  is using only the first index

Comment: ok, i added more info. it really seems that OrientDb is not very "smart" when choosing the indexes for the SQL queries..

Comment: [_This_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) explains why `source` needs to come before `position`, and that you need `(source, label)`.